# Power BI - Visualize % of total for just one of multiple distinct values

Tags: powerbi

New to Power BI so I may be asking a simple question or phasing this wrong.

Looking to create a simple line chart with the % of the total for one distinct set of values.  For example imagine a dataset with dates and then Countries in one row.  I want to make a plot of months on the X-axis with the % of a given Country on the Y-Axis.  This country would be fixed.  Lets just say Canada for sake of the example:

| Date | Country | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan | Canada | 3 |
| 02-Jan | USA | 6 |
| 03-Jan | Mexico | 2 |
| 01-Feb | Mexico | 7 |
| 02-Feb | Canada | 2 |
| 03-Feb | Canada | 3 |
| 01-Mar | USA | 5 |
| 02-Mar | Canada | 6 |
| 03-Mar | Mexico | 8 |
| 04-Mar | USA | 9 |

So in the example above Jan = 27%, Feb = 42%, Mar = 21% and then make something like this with the 30% average and a trend line as a bonus.

[image]

From my SQL background this would be dead simple - 100% clueless when it comes to PBI.  Would seem this is doable - just not obvious how.

This is like a stacked 100% bar chart but on a line chart as I would like to add a trend line and average.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Please update your question with a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) of your table with several sample rows. Do you have the % calculation? If not, % of what?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SamNseir - it's been a while since I posted a question on here.  More context added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure for your percent like so:

```
Country % = 
  DIVIDE(
    SUM(Country[Data]),
    CALCULATE( SUM(Country[Data]), REMOVEFILTERS(Country[Country]) )
  )
```

You will also need a "Month" column so that it calculates for the whole month and not per day/date.

Then for your visual, add:

- "Month column date" to the X-Axis
- `Country %` to the Y-axis
- `Country[Country]` to the Legend (optional)

Then to show just one country, either add `Country[Country]` to the visual filter, or add a Country slicer to the page.

Comment: Wow - ok.  Now that I understand the backend of PowerBI it's quite amazing.  